# ASP.NET global selector for types of element

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have several button elements that I wish to set as `visible = false` when a certain condition is met.

I have a method to do this, within which I define a list and add the required button elements. I then loop through the list and hide all these elements:

```
 Sub restrictEditAccess()
        Dim editButtons As New List(Of Control)()

        editButtons.Add(button1)
        editButtons.Add(button2)
        ...
        editButtons.Add(button9)

        For Each button In editButtons
            button.Visible = False
        Next
    End Sub
```

Is there a way in VB to do a jQuery style selector (specifically on the back-end) in order to reduce the vb code e.g.:

```
elementsWithHTMLAttribute.Attribute("data-editAccess").visible = false
```

Comment: Is there any reason, not to do it in javascript / jquery?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the buttons to appear on the front-end, I believe that click events can still come through to the back-end "click events" when they are set to disabled on the front-end.

Comment: Why disabled? Your question is about visibility.

Comment: I don't want to send the button to the client side at all. The question is about ASP.NET global selectors, not specifically visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution, which uses a bit of generics and Func magic. I have written this in C# and then onverted it to VB.net using http://converter.telerik.com/. So if there a syntax erros, you'll have to iron them out yourself - sorry.

I have the following markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Button 2"/>
<asp:Button ID="button3" runat="server" Text="Button 3" data-foo="bar"/>
<asp:Button ID="button4" runat="server" Text="Button 4"/>
```

And the following helper class:

```
Module Helper

    Function GetControls(Of T As WebControl)(ByVal cCol As ControlCollection, ByVal results As List(Of T), ByVal predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As List(Of T)
        For Each control As Control In cCol
            If TypeOf control Is T AndAlso predicate(CType(control, T)) Then results.Add(CType(control, T))
            If control.HasControls() Then GetControls(Of T)(control.Controls, results, predicate)
        Next

        Return results
    End Function

    Function GetControls(Of T As WebControl)(ByVal cCol As ControlCollection, ByVal predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As List(Of T)
        Return GetControls(cCol, New List(Of T)(), predicate)
    End Function
End Module
```

In your aspx page you can then call it using this snippet (sorry c#)

```
Private buttons = Helper.GetControls(Of Button)(Me.Controls, Function(x) x.Attributes("data-foo") = "bar")
```

What it does is pretty simple. The helper class recursively iterates over all nested ControlCollections starting from the provided parent collection, it then goes over each control and checks its type and if it matches the provided predicate. If this is the case, it adds it to the result list.

You can then do whatever you want with those controls.

Please be aware, that this code is not production ready, since it does not do any null checks and will most likely break, if you do not provide a predicate. I'll leave this as an exercise to you.

--------------------C# Original----------------------------

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<T> GetControls<T>(ControlCollection cCol, 
        List<T> results, 
        Func<T,bool> predicate) where T : WebControl
    {
        foreach (Control control in cCol)
        {
            if (control is T && predicate((T)control))
                results.Add((T)control);
            if (control.HasControls())
                GetControls<T>(control.Controls, results, predicate);
        }

        return results;
    }

    public static List<T> GetControls<T>(ControlCollection cCol, Func<T,bool> predicate) where T : WebControl
    {
        return GetControls(cCol, new List<T>(), predicate);
    }

}
```